# Prove $V$ is the direct sum of subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$ with characteristic $\neq2$. Let $\phi:V\times V\to F$ be a symmetric bilinear form that is not identically $0$. Show that there is some $v\in V$ such that $\phi(v,v)\neq0$ and $V = \langle v\rangle\oplus\langle v\rangle^\perp$.

To show that is a $v$ such that $\phi(v,v) \neq0$ suppose that there isn't. Then for all $v,w\in V$ we have $$0 = \frac12[\phi(v+w,v+w)-\phi(v,v)-\phi(w,w)] = \phi(v,w)$$
This contradicts the hypothesis that $\phi$ is not identically $0$ so there is some $v$ such that $\phi(v,v)\neq0$.

I don't konw how to show that this $v$ gives $\langle v\rangle\oplus\langle v\rangle^\perp = V$.

Comment: By $\langle v \rangle$ you mean the span of $v$?

Comment: Yes $\langle v\rangle$ is the span of $v$.

Comment: The you have it, right? I mean, you know that there is a nontrivial $v$, also the intersection between $span(v)$ and $span(v)^{\perp}$ is trivial and that the sum of those two gives you $V$. Therefore it is a direct sum.